# Conditionally add class to link_to with slim syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have a link and the code is as follows:

```
= link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path, class:{'active'}
```

and I want to add a conditional logic to the view, so if the `action_name` is same, then add class `active`

I then change to the following code

```
= link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path, class:{'active' if action_name == 'payment'}
```

but it results in error. How can I fix it.?

Comment: try this `= link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path, class: (action_name == 'payment' ? 'active' : '')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get active links there is a gem build for that [active_link_to](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to), you can use it like this and it will handle adding the active class for you:

```
=active_link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path
```

for your problem you can use this:

```
= link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path, class: (action_name == 'payment' ? 'active' : '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ......

```
= link_to 'Payment', account_payment_path, :class => action_name == 'payment' ? 'active' : ''
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's what I think is more flexible, i.e. can use with any HTML tag whether it be `a`, `li` or anything.

```
# app/helpers/menu_helper.rb
module MenuHelper
  class MenuBuilder
    def initialize(template, active_class_name, active_value)
      @template = template
      @active_class_name = active_class_name
      @active_valule = active_value
    end

    def item(value)
      contents = @template.capture { yield }
      return contents unless value == @active_value

      body = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(contents).at('body')
      # Method :+= does not always work because body.child['class'] could be nil
      body.child['class'] = "#{body.child['class']} #{@active_class_name}"
      body.inner_html.html_safe
    end
  end

  def menu_for(active_class_name, active_value)
    capture { yield MenuBuilder.new(self, active_class_name, active_value) }
  end
end
```

Rails loads this helper automatically so that you can use it in views:

```
# app/views/shared/_left_sidebar.html.slim
aside
  .menu
    ul.list
      = menu_for 'active', yield(:sidebar_menu_l1_active_value) do |m|
        = m.item 'menu-1'
          li = link_to 'Menu 1', '#'
        = m.item 'menu-2'
          li = link_to 'Menu 2', '#'
```

-

```
# app/views/home/index.html.slim
- content_for :sidebar_menu_l1_active_value, 'menu-1'
...
```